# How can I know if iCloud backup is enabled or not?

Tags: ios, icloud

How can I know programmatically if user has iCloud backup activated or not? I'm not talking about allowing a specific app store data or documents using URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier. I'm talking about the general backup (all the device), similar to iTunes synchronization.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't. And I don't know why you need to know....

Comment: Just to suggest to the user he or she can activate it and then have online or cloud backups.

Comment: The point is to tell them they could lose data, and the conditions under which it is so, if they don't.  Nothing nefarious or pointless about that in the slightest.